# Excel Range to Cell value conversion

Tags: excel, vba

As we write Range(A4) as Cell(1,4).How should I need write Range(A2:AB256) into Cell format?

Thanks,
Arup

Comment: @fencliff Can you help me in the following post of mine? --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763603/excel-column-delete-using-vbscript/13765901#13765901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly, you can't, but if your goal is to access a range of cells by their indexes, you can use the Range-method with two cells as arguments:

```
Set myRange = mySheet.Range(mySheet.Cells(1, 2), mySheet.Cells(28, 256))
```

Or you can parse the column letter from the cell address:

```
Dim columnNumber As Integer
Dim columnLetter As String

columnNumber = 5
columnLetter = Split(Cells(1, columnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
```

Comment: OK, But Is there any other way to get the Excel cloumn Alaphabetic value? Say I have a Value Under the column number 5. So if i know the column number, can i anyway get the Alphabetic value of the column which is actually "I"?

Comment: Edited my answer. It's a bit of a hack, but it seems to work. There might be a better way, I just can't remember one.

Comment: I have multiple sheets in the spreadsheet,but i want it to work on my first sheet.So if i write it in this way columnLetter = Split(Sheet(1).Cells(1, columnNumber).Address, "$")(1) --- will it work for me?

Comment: That method only returns the column letter, so it doesn't matter which sheet you use. The fifth column is letter E on every sheet. But yes, you can refer to a specific worksheet. I think the syntax is `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)`

Comment: I worte the code as  objSheet3.Range(objSheet3.Cells(1,1),objSheet3.Cells(DataCount,ParentColmnCount)).Copy
objSheet6.Range(objSheet6.Cells(1,1),objSheet6.Cells(DataCount,ParentColmnCount)).PasteSpecial
objSheet6.Activate --But it is copying only the first column values from the Sheet(3) to the first column of first column sheet(6)....Any idea why the full is not pasting out?

Comment: One More Question any idea about the syntax of how to add a new column between two adjacent columns which are filled with data?

Comment: If you have another question, I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: Can you help me in the following post of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763603/excel-column-delete-using-vbscript/13765901#13765901

Comment: can you help me in the below post?----http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746909/how-to-add-column-in-excel-using-vbscript

Comment: can you help me in the below post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788755/string-search-with-in-the-excel-column-values-row-wise/13788821#comment18964056_13788821