# String search with in the excel column values row wise

Tags: vbscript

I have an Excel sheet which has 200 columns. Now number of rows are 3500. So i have to search a string if it presents within any column for each row. Now to make the process fatser,I am looking for any alternate instead of Looping technique. Is there any such?

```
IntRow6 = 2
DataCount = 0

Do While objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).Value <> ""
  For DataCount = 0 to UBound(VMHArray)
        IntClmn3 = 1        
        Do While 1 = 1
            If objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,IntClmn3).Value = VMHArray(DataCount) Then
                objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,IntClmn3+2).Value=objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,IntClmn3+5).Value
                Exit Do
            End If
            IntClmn3 = IntClmn3 + 1
        Loop
    Next
    IntRow6 = IntRow6 + 1
Loop
```

The above is taking to much time, thus i am looking for an equivalent VBScript code which can run more faster search.

**EDIT:**

```
ParentColmnCount=ParentColmnCount-1
IntRow6=2
DataCount=0

Do While objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).Value <> ""
    For DataCount=0 to UBound(VMHArray)
        If objSheet6.Range(objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1),objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,ParentColmnCo‌​unt)).Find(VMHArray(DataCount)) <> Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Hi")
        End If
    Next
    IntRow6=IntRow6+1
Loop
```

I'm getting any error saying that, "Object variable not set" error at the Range line of the above code.

***UPDATE***

I have updated my code as per your suggestion,and modified the declaration of variables as below:

Option Explicit

Dim objExcel1,objWorkbook

Dim strPathExcel1

Dim objSheet6,objSheet3

Dim IntRow6,IntRow3

Dim IntClmn3

Dim DataCount,ParentColmnCount

Dim Falg

Dim TaskCounter

Dim r As Range
Dim s As Variant

But I am getting the error again: Expected end of statement" in the line "Dim r As Range"

Comment: ParentColmnCount=ParentColmnCount-1
IntRow6=2
DataCount=0
Do While objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1).Value <> ""

    For DataCount=0 to UBound(VMHArray)
  
        If objSheet6.Range(objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1),objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,ParentColmnCount)).Find(VMHArray(DataCount)) <> Nothing Then
 
  MsgBox("Hi")
 
 End If
        
    Next

IntRow6=IntRow6+1
Loop

Comment: @pete But getting any error saying that, "Object variable not set" error at the Range line of the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Range.Find` (which returns a `Range` object). It's faster than a loop.

Example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim matched As Range

    'Get the second row
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("2:2")
    Set matched = r.Find("myString")

    'Do stuff with matched
End Sub
```

**UDPATE:**

Assuming you are using `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, then the `Range` object will be present (as `CreateObject` will return an instance of Excel which contains `Range` objects and functionality).

For further proof, you're already looping through the worksheet using `Range` objects ([`Cells` is a `Range` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx)).

**UPDATE:**

Here's a more advanced example. Assume the following data in on `Sheet1`:

```
fred    ethel   ricky   bobby   1   2   3   4
lucy    myrtle  fonzy   rickie  1   2   3   4
joanie  chachie donna   patty   1   2   3   4
selma   homer   lisa    bart    1   2   3   4
```

You can loop through the ranges like so:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim names(3) As String
    Dim s As Variant

    names(0) = "ethel"
    names(1) = "fonzy"
    names(2) = "patty"
    names(3) = "selma"

    For Each s In names
        For Each r In Sheet1.Cells.CurrentRegion.Find(s)
            r.Offset(0, 4).Value = r.Offset(0, 4).Value + 1000
        Next r
    Next s
End Sub
```

After the routine is done, the data is now:

```
fred    ethel   ricky   bobby   1   1002    3   4
lucy    myrtle  fonzy   rickie  1   2   1003    4
joanie  chachie donna   patty   1   2   3   1004
selma   homer   lisa    bart    1001    2   3   4
```

**UPDATE:**
I just saw your comment on your question (and edited your question to include the updated code).

You're getting "Object variable not set" on that line because you cannot use `<>` comparisons with objects. Change the line to read:

```
If Not objSheet6.Range(objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,1),objSheet6.Cells(IntRow6,ParentColmnCo‌​unt)).Find(VMHArray(DataCount)) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: I Want this functionality to implement in VBScript.Can you confirm if the Range Object is present in VBScript?

Comment: Does Find method return only True or False? and May i also get the matched column number also?

Comment: It returns a `Range` object which can also be a collection. You'd access the column number by `matched.Column`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736(v=office.14).aspx for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have one more query. You mentioned in the below code Set r = Sheet1.Range("2:2"). but in my code i used Loop to access every row. So I need to use variable instead of constant value. So any idea here also?

Comment: in your code you said Range("2:2"),but i used while loop to access each row.So i can't use constant,instead need to use variable.but how to frame any idea?

Comment: Can you help me in my new question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798858/row-data-partition-empty-column-values-in-a-row-in-one-side-and-non-empties-ar#comment18983534_13798858